# How to display single record in the database if duplicate records are available using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

My table is:

```
sid    fname   lname    subject  phno
---    -----   -----    -------- -----
1      vvk     v        math     4444
1      vvk     v        read     4444
2      hari    h        math     5555
2      hari    h        read     5555
3      kalyan  k        math     6666
3      kalyan  k        read     6666
```

How can I display a single record from the student has take subject math or read, like this:

```
1      vvk     v        math     4444
```

How to write query in hibernate to get the above output?

the table contains composite id on sid and subject fields

### Mysql Mapping File is

### Student.hbm.xml:

```
  <composite-id>
  <key-property name="sid" column="sid" type="string"/>
  <key-property name="subject" column="subject" type="string"/>
  </composite-id>
```

Comment: What's the name of the table? `student`? How do you wanna retrieve it? Criteria API or SQL statement?

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and add a primary key to your table.

Comment: the table name is student  sqlStatenment  or criteria to retrive the answer already the table have composite key with sid and subject fields

Comment: If you want to write an HQL query, we need to see the Student class with at least the id field and the composite key class.

Answer (score 0):

If the PK is [sid, subject], then the ID of the Student entity should be a class containing these two fields, and you would use it the same way as you would do with a non-composite primary key:

```
StudentKey key = new StudentKey(someSid, someSubject);
Student student = (Student) session.get(Student.class, key);
```

If this is not clear enough, then edit your question and show how you defined the entity mapped to this table.

Answer (score 0):

With this kind of composite key, just create an instance of `Student` and set the attributes for the key. Then you can load the desired row into the instance with `session.load()` method. Follow this example:

```
Student student = new Student();
student.setSid("1");
student.setSubject("math");
session.load(Student.class, student);
```

The call to `session.load(Student.class, student)` will load the persistent state of this student into the `student` instance.